# G is isomorphic to the direct sum of H, K under these condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The third excersie from Hungerford's book on page 61.

[image]

My attempt:

If G is isomorphic to the direct sum of H,K, those condition are easily satisfied. $\pi_{1}$|(h,k) to h (where I despite the k component) is a homomorphism. $L_1$|h to (h,0) where 0 is the additive identity. Similarly, when n=2, we do the same with k. The above Homomorphism satisfy all condition listed in the problem.

The converse is a bit tricky to prove though, and I am not sure if my proof is completed enough.  Assuming the $\pi_n$ and $ L_n$ above exist, then G have two subgroups H' and K' intersecting trivially and isomorphic to H,and K respectively. I can't say that H'=H, and K'= K though.

Now since G is abelian and because  $<H',K'>$ $\subset$ G, having such H',K' implies G has order at least |H||K| . note that |H|=|H'| , |K|=|K'|.

The condition near the end of the exercise implies that |G| is at most |H||K|. Therefore, $<H',K'>$ = H'K' = G since they are all abelian.  The mapping $\phi$ from direct sum of H,K to HK given by  (h,k) to hk is an isomorphism. Again, it is because all of them are abelian.